# What material to make a custom sewer trap access pit lid from?

Tags: metal, sewer, plastic, metal-cutting

Just had my sewer line redone in my basement and when they poured in the concrete it created a trapezoidal shape and the dimensions are not standard.  This is similar to covering a sump pit in the basement, but in my case, it's the cover over the house traps on 2 sewer lines and covers an area bout the size of a bath towel.  36" long and 18" wide on the narrow end, 24" wide on the wider end.

[image]

What's the best material to make a lid/cover from.  Should I just cut plywood and call it a day, or is there an easy inexpensive plastic or metal that I can get custom cut to size?  Maybe a large plastic lid or something I can shave down or just lay on top and anchor in some way?  I don't have a lot of tools so something that can either be ordered cut to size or modified with simple at-home tools would be great.

I'm thinking I can either cut the wood to size, or get a larger metal sheet that I just lay over the entire shape and not have it be something that's custom fit.  Does it need to be flush to the ground for some code issue that I don't know about?

Comment: I'm not clear what you are attempting to cover.  A "sewer line" should be a pipe that is fully enclosed.  It should have a cleanout but that should have its own cover.  Perhaps a photo or two of what you have here would be helpful.

Comment: "Flush to the ground" - not sure about code but the lawnmower may find it if it is not flush...

Comment: I added pictures of other examples (that are not mine), it's in the basement and it's irregularly sized and a bit bigger in area than the nice ones in the photos.

Comment: What goal are you trying to achieve by covering this? Should people be able to walk on it, put things on it, or is it just for aesthetics? That would in part dictate the material.

Comment: It should be strong enough to stand on, whether or not you care about that.  Depending on size and material it might need additional support or structure underneath.  Does it have to be flush?  Depends on the location.  Don't create a trip hazard.  Photos of your actual situation would help.

Comment: @FreeMan - The workers are finished, so now I can take an actual picture and I've uploaded.  I was trying to get in early to maybe see if I needed to run to the store to get a lid or something they can cast the concrete around... but not quick enough so this is what they'll leave me with - except for a channel they still need to cut to make room for a flush lid.

Comment: Yikes!! Did they give a good reason for doing that? If you've got the tools to do the work, I'd buy the box from [jay's answer](https://diy.stackexchange.com/a/236158/34147) that's big enough to cover the whole thing, then modify it to fit the lip they carve you - cut an angled chunk from the lid, then cut a rabbet on that new edge to fit the lip. Even better, I'd ask _them_ to do it for leaving you such a mess.

Comment: Well I think they just did the least amount of chopping they could get away with - started off with a small rectangle which they expanded to fit my new automatic gate valve (which is the big round thing) and that's why it has the weird shape,

Comment: @freeman the valve box is intended to be placed *inside* an oversized hole, lid flush with surface, and then backfilled from outside.  I've edited my answer to say it cannot be used now that the hole has been set in concrete.

Comment: I understood that, @jay613. I was _thinking_ (having not seen a valve box in person recently), that the lid would have a lip that OP could use, then be custom cut & relipped to fit. The lid itself is sturdy enough to be walked on when installed properly, I figured it would continue to be so in this application. Perhaps I thought wrong...

Comment: @freeman that would be a good option if they had formed and sized the concrete cutout just right for a valve box lid.  The lids are cheap and strong and last forever. 
 Of course the easy way to do that would be to use the valve box and pour concrete around it!    But I think this hole is too big for any single box or lid, and given its size and shape, it will be easier to make one from plywood.

Comment: I have a hole like that for my sump. It's covered with an old dock plate, but those are a few hundred dollars minimum. As would be anything other than a piece of plywood. ***Is screwing plywood to the slab to cover a hole code complaint?*** +1, because cutting a recess is out of the question; be easier to re-pour. (I get stuck at the *ADA 1/4" maximum* when I search, which is N/A)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

New answer, based on your new picture.

Cut a sheet of 3/4 inch plywood to fit the opening.  Enforce it underneath with wood or with L shaped bars normally used for shelving.  Connect wooden legs that will fit in the four corners of this pit so they rest on the bottom.   So you have something constructed like a simple table, but not rectangular, fitting flush inside the opening and sitting on the bottom in the corners.

The enforcement may not be necessary.  The legs can be attached to the cover so they come out with it, or they can be attached to the pit walls so they just support the cover.

Another option if the plumbers are still there and they have the ability to grind and set concrete is to ask them to create a groove around the top that is rectangular overall, at least 2 inches bigger than the hole all around, and 3/4 inch deep so you can just drop a rectangular piece of 3/4 inch plywood in it.

What I mean is this: They dig a groove 3/4 inch deep all around the pit up to the red line.  Where the line is CLOSEST to the pit, it should have some minimum overhang like about 2 inches.  Then you just drop a piece of 3/4 inch plywood on it, with a 1/2 inch hole cut out as shown for pulling it out.   The environment is probably damp so you can paint the board with a suitable protective paint in the color of the basement floor.

[image]

Comment: so the concrete guy said that he'll come back and cut out a groove for me when I get a lid - and that he'll make the groove rectangular so that I wouldn't have to deal with the weird shape - which I kind of can picture if he just shaves down 6" of top surface from the narrower end.

Comment: That's great.  Not sure what you mean about six inches.  I've added a picture of what I mean to my answer.

Answer (score 2):

**EDIT:**  Leaving this answer here for posterity but now that you have updated the photo in the question to show your own actual situation, I see the pit has already been formed in concrete so you cannot use a valve box.

---

An easy way to do this is with valve boxes.  They come with flush-fit lids that are strong enough to stand on.    They are CHEAP.  If you have a large or odd-shaped area you can use multiple valve boxes next to each other.  You can safely cut out chunks from the sides to provide a single large internal space as long as you leave enough structure to support the lids.  You can get different color lids (black, grey, brown) too.

It's important to note that in your photos, and presumably in your actual situation, the traps and pipes are all fully sealed.  This is not a sewage pit.  It is just an access cover to equipment that is located below floor level.  So it does not require a sealed cover.

[image: Valve box]